# JavaFX динамическое добавление элементов в combobox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

В системе производится циклический поиск элементов(идентификаторы устройств), которые записываются в combobox `XBEES`. В начале поиска бокс чистится (чтобы ID не повторялись) `XBEES.getItems().clear();` а потом добавляются заново (возможно, что какх то уже не будет, а какие то появятся, но в основном большинство ID остаются такие же). Это было просто и удобно, но проблема в том, что при таком режиме если выберешь элемент, то после следующего цикла он исчезнет (combo-box опустеет) и выбирать элемент придется заново (цикл обновления частый секунд 10 обычно). Как реализовать вариант только с добавлением новых ID а-ля цикл (от 0 до числа элементов combobox) {если ID[i] == ID пометить, что перезаписались} если не перезаписалось, то добавить ID

Comment: то есть в комбобоксе в принципе нет операций аналогичных массиву? (подсчет числа элементов, сравнение с элементом комбобокса определенной строки)

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример, как можно динамически добавлять/удалять элементы `comboBox`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main extends Application {

    private ComboBox<Integer> comboBox;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        Button button = new Button("Go");
        button.setOnAction(this::updateItems);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(button, comboBox), 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateItems(ActionEvent event) {
        final List<Integer> newData = getNewData();
        synchronized (comboBox) {
            // Элементы, которые есть в comboBox и которых нет в новом наборе, должны быть удалены
            List<Integer> removeList = comboBox.getItems().stream()
                    .filter(item -> !newData.contains(item))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            // Элементы, которые есть в новом наборе и которых нет в comboBox, должны быть добавлены
            List<Integer> addList = newData.stream()
                    .filter(item -> !comboBox.getItems().contains(item))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            comboBox.getItems().removeAll(removeList);
            comboBox.getItems().addAll(addList);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Новый набор данных. На основании которого из comboBox должен быть удален элемент со значением 3, и добавлен
     * элемент со значением 6
     *
     * @return Набор данных
     */
    private List<Integer> getNewData() {
        List<Integer> newIds = new ArrayList<>();
        newIds.add(1);
        newIds.add(2);
        newIds.add(4);
        newIds.add(5);
        newIds.add(6);
        return newIds;
    }

}
```